# How to get the history of an object in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I added a new field in one of my models and I would like to full it in with the name of a user who did a certain action (here, Validated by: USER).

The easiest way I see is to get it from the history where this infos already is.

[image: Just so you see exactly what page I'm talking about]

From this picture, for example, I would get the User 'admin' if he performed the action 'Changed email'

**How to get the history of an object (as seen in the django Admin) ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That info is stored in the `LogEntry` model.

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
```

and its definition is:

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(_('action time'), auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(_('object id'), blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(_('object repr'), max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('action flag'))
    change_message = models.TextField(_('change message'), blank=True)

    objects = LogEntryManager()
```

More info in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L24)

Make sure that you access this in ***ReadOnly*** mode, else you would be messing up your log history.