# Django. Print all admin actions.

Tags: django, django-admin

Someone in my team deleted an important object. I need to know who did it, he obviously had access to the admin. Is there a way I can print to the terminal (or anywhere) all the admin actions of the last 3 hours? I'm sure django keeps a history, I just don't know where to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the history of an object in django admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612142/how-to-get-the-history-of-an-object-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 1):

This solved it:

```
>>> from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
>>> x = LogEntry.objects.all().order_by("-id")[:200]
>>> for y in x:
...   print("%s - %s" % (y.action_time, y.change_message))
```